# SQL - connecting data from multiple tables, over foreign key

Tags: sql

I'm breaking my head over following problem that I can't figure out.

I have three tables containing data about:
students (table students), 
courses (table courses) and 
studies (table studies).

Besides those tables, I have two connection tables.

One connects students, studies and courses over their ids and contains extra column year (during which student started studies) and other connects courses and studies over their ids and contains extra column semester.

Every student goes to certain study and is studying certain courses depending on semester.
Every study has certain number of courses depending on semester.

Connection tables looks like this.

**Table(connection_study_course_student)**

StudyID|CourseID|StudentID|Year

**Table (connection_study_course)**

CourseID|StudyID|Semester

My problem is following. I need info about which students are enrolled on which courses and to do that, I have to enter loads of data. Example: First semester has eight courses. I have to enter eight values for each student enrolled in first semester in table connection_study_course_student. I have ten studies, so it's lots of data which, I'm sure, can be put better than like it's now.

**StudyID|CourseID|StudentID|Year**

- 1 1 1 2019
- 1 2 1 2019
- 1 3 1 2019
- 1 4 1 2019
- 1 5 1 2019
- 1 6 1 2019
- 1 7 1 2019
- 1 8 1 2019

What can I do to connect already existing data, without so much hassle? I'd like to be able to enter student_ID, studies_ID and someother_ID which would give me info about what student is enrolled on which study and what courses he listenes.

Comment: Which SQL product are you using? Are you looking to do JOIN on the 3 tables? If yes, what kind of result are you looking for (use the right column names)?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server. 

I'm not searching for a query. I'm looking for a solution, which would allow me to enter only one value next to studentID instead of eight. 
So, when I'm entering data in my table (connection_study_course_student) I enter (1 1 1 2019) for student with id=1 on study id=1 which is enrolled on courses with id=1. 
That third id should allow me to extract all courses certain student is enrolled on, when writing a query. 

Right now, I have to enter separately, one row for every course certain student is enrolled on.

Comment: You might be looking for [SQL Server UPDATE JOIN](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-update-join/).

Comment: Thank you. I'm pretty new to this, so I'm not sure if your suggestion works for me, but I'll check it out.